# How to do email-confirmation after registration in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django's authentication system. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at James Bennett's [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) project.