# django registration and sending activation email

Tags: python, django

Like the title suggest, i am having problems sending my activation email.

It gives me [Errno 61] Connection refused when i press my activate email button.

Can someone guide me on how to configure the settings?

My current settings.py

```
# Registration settings
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 2
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Also if there is a need to implement SMTP, tell me how too.

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do email-confirmation after registration in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536766/how-to-do-email-confirmation-after-registration-in-django)

Comment: Of course there's a need to implement SMTP. If you're going to use localhost as your mail server, you need an SMTP server running on it to send the email.

Comment: Check out this if you don't want to go to the hassle of setting up SMTP on your dev machine/server https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#testing-email-sending

Comment: I tried the method provided by pastylegs but i'm still getting that error msg.

Comment: What i did was open up another terminal window and input that command with the python manage.py runserver running in another window. is that how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to open up another terminal window and put in the command: python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025

That would solve all things